# Android Material 3 Light theme LIstView items text hidden

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-sdk-tools

I am learning Android here. My aim is to display the Cursor I get from calling SQLiteDatabase.query() in a ListView. Using a ContentProvider. I cannot see the text of the list items although I am certain the textual data is comming to the screen from the database because I can see the list items separator lines and even get that little animation when I touch any item. Please help me realize what could be the problem. I am suspecting with my little knowledge gained so far it is a color attribute I have to change in my configuration of material 3 light theme I am using, but i have no idea which attribute exactly.
The following is the Java code

```java
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        insertNote("New note");

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(NotesProvider.CONTENT_URI,
                NotesTable.COLUMNS_LIST, null,null, null, null);
        String[] from = {NotesTable.NOTE_TEXT};
        int[] to = {android.R.id.text1};
        CursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cursor, from, to, 0);

        ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        listView.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);

    }

    private void insertNote(String noteText) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(NotesTable.NOTE_CREATED, noteText);
        Uri noteUri = getContentResolver().insert(NotesProvider.CONTENT_URI, values);
        Log.d("MainActivityDebug", "Inserted note " + noteUri.getLastPathSegment());
    }
```

The following is the layout file

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The following is how I have customind the default theme

```xml
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="NoteDown" parent="Theme.Material3.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/text_color_primary</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

The following is the result screen, notice the list item separator lines
[image]

Lastly I want an experienced developer who has been developing for Android for a long time probably before 2015 to tell me whether it is too oldschool to use a Content provider to manage database operations and if it is what I should use. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I Found the answer to this problem when I investigated the database created by the app when it launches. I made a mistake when defining the insertNote() by inserting the newly created note into the wrong column of the database table other than the intended column. Therefore whenever I retrieved data from the intended column all rows had a value of null for that column, and the content I was looking for was in another column.

Also, after correcting this, I had to add android:textColor attribute in my theme configuration to give the list item text a color that is contrasting with the white color of my background. You guys should have suggested at least this one(tongue in the cheek).